# How to update column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I can not find the error while update the existing column with autogenerated record

Here is my table structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeRegistration]
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Sr_no] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Branch_Code] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Employee_Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Designation] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Date_of_Joining] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Reporting_To] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Staff_Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Reporting_To_1] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Staff_Code_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Emp_Staff_Code]  AS ('T'+right('0000'+CONVERT([varchar](8),[Sr_no],(0)),(8))),
    [Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [confirmPassword] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMAIL_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Created_By] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Created_On] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Modified_By] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Modified_Date] [date] NOT NULL
)
```

I want to update `Password` column with below query:-

```
use AxpressDB 

alter table EmployeeRegistration 
   alter column Password AS ('XP'+right('0123'+CONVERT([varchar](50),[Sr_no],(0)),(8)))
```

Comment: Yes - and ?!?!?! Do you get an error?? If so: please **post it here** since we cannot read neither your screen, nor your mind!

Comment: Error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the column altering :

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename
    ALTER COLUMN columnname columndatatype(size)
```

and the example :

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exy 
    ALTER COLUMN column_a DECIMAL (5, 2) ;
```

Try these manner

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter an existing column and make it as computed column, you need to drop and recreate

```
alter table EmployeeRegistration 
   drop column Password 
alter table EmployeeRegistration 
   add Password AS ('XP'+right('0123'+CONVERT([varchar](50),[Sr_no],(0)),(8)))
```